# Error while using reshape function in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
  id  sex age trt.1 response.1 trt.2 response.2
1  1 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
2  2 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
3  3 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
4  4    M  28     A          1     B          1
5  5    F  39     A          1     B          1
6  6    M  47     A          1     B          1
```

I want to change it to

```
  id  sex age times response
1  1 <NA>  NA  A      1
2  1 <NA>  NA  B      1
3  2 <NA>  NA  A      1
4  2 <NA>  NA  B      1
.
.
.
.
```

I tried the following,

```
reshape(merged, idvar = "id", varying = list(4:7), v.names="response", times=c("A","B"), direction="long")
```

But I am getting this error,

```
Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  : 
  'times' is wrong length
```

I tried times = C("A","B","A","B") that time I get the output, but the original data frame is 70 rows and the output should be 140 rows, but when I use this I am get 280 rows which is wrong. Can anybody help me where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're expecting? You just need to change `varying = list(4:7)` to `varying = list(c(4,6), c(5,7))` since you are actually melting two pieces simultaneously.

```
dd <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, text = "id  sex age trt.1 response.1 trt.2 response.2
1  1 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
2  2 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
3  3 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
4  4    M  28     A          1     B          1
5  5    F  39     A          1     B          1
6  6    M  47     A          1     B          1")


reshape(dd, idvar = "id", varying = list(c(4,6), c(5,7)), direction="long",
        v.names = c('trt','response'))

#     id  sex age time trt response
# 1.1  1 <NA>  NA    1   A        1
# 2.1  2 <NA>  NA    1   A        1
# 3.1  3 <NA>  NA    1   A        1
# 4.1  4    M  28    1   A        1
# 5.1  5    F  39    1   A        1
# 6.1  6    M  47    1   A        1
# 1.2  1 <NA>  NA    2   B        1
# 2.2  2 <NA>  NA    2   B        1
# 3.2  3 <NA>  NA    2   B        1
# 4.2  4    M  28    2   B        1
# 5.2  5    F  39    2   B        1
# 6.2  6    M  47    2   B        1
```

Comment: Your output doesn't give the exact output which I want. Though it gives me an idea of how to do it. Can you help me in correctly it? response should be 1s no As and Bs

Comment: @haimen that's what your v.names and times arguments did, see edits

Answer (score 0):

Reshape is awesome but I really don't see why you need to use it in this case.

```
text = "id  sex age trt.1 response.1 trt.2 response.2
1  1 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
2  2 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
3  3 <NA>  NA     A          1     B          1
4  4    M  28     A          1     B          1
5  5    F  39     A          1     B          1
6  6    M  47     A          1     B          1"

data <- read.table(text = text)

result1 <- data[, c("id", "sex", "age", "trt.1", "response.1")]
result2 <- data[, c("id", "sex", "age", "trt.2", "response.2")]

names(result1) <- c("id", "sex", "age", "trt", "response")
names(result2) <- c("id", "sex", "age", "trt", "response")

result <- rbind(result1, result2)
```

Here is the output:

```
id  sex age trt response
1   1 <NA>  NA   A        1
2   2 <NA>  NA   A        1
3   3 <NA>  NA   A        1
4   4    M  28   A        1
5   5    F  39   A        1
6   6    M  47   A        1
11  1 <NA>  NA   B        1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tidyr way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  gather(variable, value,
         trt.1:response.2) %>%
  separate(variable, c("variable", "number")) %>%
  spread(variable, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt` from `library(data.table)` which can take multiple `measure` columns with the `pattern` argument

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
melt(setDT(df2), measure=patterns('^trt', 'response'), value.name=c('times', 'response'))
#    id  sex age variable times response
# 1:  1 <NA>  NA        1     A        1
# 2:  2 <NA>  NA        1     A        1
# 3:  3 <NA>  NA        1     A        1
# 4:  4    M  28        1     A        1
# 5:  5    F  39        1     A        1
# 6:  6    M  47        1     A        1
# 7:  1 <NA>  NA        2     B        1
# 8:  2 <NA>  NA        2     B        1
# 9:  3 <NA>  NA        2     B        1
#10:  4    M  28        2     B        1
#11:  5    F  39        2     B        1
#12:  6    M  47        2     B        1
```